# seaborn FacetGrid empty

Tags: seaborn, facet-grid

A simple dataset, with one column named "measurement" with about 20 distinct values, and another one named "value".

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col='measurement',col_wrap=4)
g.map(sns.displot,'value')
```

I get an error about the number of plots matplotlib.pyplot creates

> RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
> fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrow, ncol, **kwargs)

The 2 lines of code return me a long column with all the individual graphs and , at the end, an empty FacetGrid (snippet below). I have no idea why this is happening, anybody have a thought?

[image: output]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried,

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col='measurement',col_wrap=4)
g.map(sns.displot,'value')
```

I also got same results, but changing to **distplot** or **histplot** gave me the desired results. If that's what you've wanted.[image]

Comment: hei , you were right, histplot works. But i kind-o wanted that kde curve also. You think this is an issue I should raise on the github? It doesn't seem normal to me, that one kind of plot work while the other jumps on pyplot instead of facetgrid.  Thanks !

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2288) page?